# Error while running make to install drivers

Tags: drivers, realtek, install-from-source

Everytime I want to run `make` while installing a driver, I get these error messages :

```
make[1]: ***[_module_/home/alaa/Downloads/rtl_92ce_92se_92de_8723ae_linux_mac80211_0006.0514.2012] Error 2 
make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: * [all] Error 2
```

How can I get this solved?

Comment: The error message seems to be truncated, can you edit your question with the correct, complete error message?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your kernel header files are missing :

Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-YOUR-KERNEL-VERSION`. Then try `make` again or `sudo make`

Comment: I've already done this. I really don't know what is going on

Comment: Try with sudo make